# records are not saving into database using php in android

Tags: php, android

Hi In the below I am creating group chat application for that I am passing the below details using action=createGroup from client side.

**java**

```
public String CreateGroup(String groupname,String username,
            ArrayList<FriendInfo> result) throws UnsupportedEncodingException  {

         List<String> usersName = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) { 
            usersName.add(result.get(i).userName); 
            }
                String params = "groupname="+ URLEncoder.encode(groupname,"UTF-8") +
                        "&username="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.username,"UTF-8") +
                        "&password="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.password,"UTF-8") +
                        "&friendUserName=" +usersName+      
                        "&action="  + URLEncoder.encode("CreateGroup","UTF-8")+
                        "&";

            Log.i("PARAMS", params);
            return socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);
```

This is my server side code.Where I did mistake because data not saving into database.Can any one please help me

**php**

```
   case "CreateGroup":
    $userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password);

    if ($userId != NULL)

    {

        if (isset($_REQUEST['friendUserName']))         
        {               
             $friendUserNames = $_REQUEST['friendUserName'];
            $friendUserNames = str_replace('[','',$friendUserNames);
            $friendUserNames = str_replace(']','',$friendUserNames);
            $friendUserNames = explode(",", $friendUserNames);
            foreach($friendUserNames as $friendUserName){

             $groupname = $_REQUEST['groupname'];

             $sql = "select Id from users where username='$friendUserName' limit 1";
             echo $sql;
             if ($result = $db->query($sql))

             {
                    if ($row = $db->fetchObject($result))

                    {
                         $requestId = $row->Id;

                         $groupname = $row->Id;

                         if ($row->Id != $userId)
                         {
                                 $sql = "insert into group (groupname,providerId, requestId)values(".$groupname.",".$userId.",".$requestId.")";
                                 echo $sql;


                                 if ($db->query($sql))
                                 {
                                        $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                        $out = FAILED;
                                 }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $out = FAILED;  
                        }                                                
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $out = FAILED;                      
                    }
             }

             else
             {
                    $out = FAILED;
             }              
        }
        }
        else
        {
                $out = FAILED;
        }           
    }
    else
    {
        $out = FAILED;
    }   
break;
```

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `group` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `groupname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `providerId` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `requestId` int(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `group`
--
ALTER TABLE `group`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `username` (`providerId`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `userid` (`providerId`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `ufriendid` (`requestId`);
```

Comment: what's the output of second echo $sql; ??

Comment: @noob Second echo not printing anything it's giving FAILED

Comment: how abot first echo $sql;??

Comment: @noob select Id from users where username='[user3,user1]

Comment: @user1: You are passing total array as a string to this query. The format how you are sending is wrong. It should come like: select Id from users where username='user3'

Comment: you see $_REQUEST['friendUserName'] is posting more than one username. So you need to handle it properly

Comment: @noob from client side the output giving ike this username=user2&password=user2&action=CreateGroup&friendUserName=[user3,user1]&groupname=New

Comment: @noob  where I want to change this one

Comment: @sUndeep exactly I want like that only but that should be more than one value I want to pass as a paramter

Comment: @user1: One way is: You have to split the string [user3,user1] and in a for loop call the query $sql1.

Comment: @sUndeep after , can i split and i want to store into variable

Comment: see in php there' one method to split string into array. Now you will have two array elements: [user3 and user1] Then loop this array in for loop. Inside for loop replace the '[' & ']' and assign to a variable and call $sql. If you still didn't get my point, give me some time i will give you code snippet.

Comment: Refer noob. He has given the right code what I tried to say in my above comment.

Comment: yes That code also used in my post

Comment: @sUndeep small doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_REQUEST['friendUserName'] is posting more than one username(an array). So you need to handle it properly

try replacing:

```
$friendUserName = $_REQUEST['friendUserName'];
```

with

```
$friendUserNames = $_REQUEST['friendUserName'];
$friendUserNames = str_replace('[','',$friendUserNames);
$friendUserNames = str_replace(']','',$friendUserNames);
$friendUserNames = explode(",", $friendUserNames);
foreach($friendUserNames as $friendUserName){
//your rest of code as it is 
} //and end tag for for loop at appropriate position from your code before the last second else
```